# Shift dropdown to fit on the screen for Foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 6.1.2

The page with the dropdowns is http://dev.golightlyplus.com/wig/website/properties.html

The last dropdown for "Contact" goes off the screen.

What is the cleanest way to make sure it appears fully on the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is that you can move your nav from the right (but you probably already know that) so the second one is to override css `left` property.

```
.dropdown.menu:not(.vertical) .is-dropdown-submenu.first-sub:last-child {
    left: -100px;
}
```